# Where do the powers come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-craft

In *The Craft*, prior to invoking Manon, where does the power that the other three girls seem to have come from?

It's nowhere near as strong as Sarah's power, who is a natural witch. She's the one who actually seems to be responsible for pretty much every spell before Manon steps in. Nancy is obviously a little stronger herself, killing her step-father. Bonnie and Rochelle do virtually nothing, but I suppose being able to even assist in invoking Manon means they must have SOME ability.

Where does it come from? Did they just study to learn their powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They usually got all their reading and practice material from the supply store (spell books, candles etc.). So its safe to assume they are not natural witches but acquired powers through learning and studying witchcraft.

I think it had more to do with the reading and practice of witchcraft and firm belief that it works.